# Does CDC cover data schema changes?

Tags: database, etl, change-data-capture

We are trying to develop a data extraction module with changed data capture (CDC).

For the toolkit to use, we are tentatively considering 1) Kafka, Debezium, and/or Airbyte, 2) Logstash, or 3) any other platform, so please remind me if I missed something.

CDC will capture changes of Insert, Update, and Delete, e.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2);
UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2 WHERE condition;
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;
```

However, we wonder whether CDC captures changes to the data schema, also known as the Data Definition Language (DDL), e.g.:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column3 datatype;
```

We highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

Comment: It depends on the tool you use

Comment: Having recently implemented Airbyte with OSS terraform. One can set how Airbyte handles syncs when it detects a non-breaking schema change in the source via [non_breaking_schema_updates_behavior](
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/airbytehq/airbyte/latest/docs/resources/connection#non_breaking_schema_updates_behavior). Airbyte with a CDC connection can detect and propogate column changes with the following options: "ignore", "disable_connection", "propagate_columns", "propagate_fully". https://airbyte.com/blog/airbyte-schema-propagation-keeping-your-replicated-catalog-up-to-date